# How to get Sheet Name of individual Sheets in Google Spreadsheet - Google Sheet Api v4 - Java

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get sheet name of individual sheets in Google Spreadsheet using Google Sheet Api v4.

I tried the following way that gets the properties:

```
  Spreadsheet response1= service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).setIncludeGridData (false).execute ();

  System.out.println (response1.getProperties ().getTitle ());
```

However it displays the name of the actual Spreadsheet rather than displaying the names of individual sheets in the Spreadsheet.

Do anyone know how we can go about it?

Answer (score 5):

Below is the answer to above question:

```
Spreadsheet response1= service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).setIncludeGridData (false)
.execute ();

System.out.println (response1.getSheets ().get (0).getProperties ().getTitle ());
```

Answer (score 3):

Here, you can iterate over the `workSheetList` to get all individual sheet title.

```
Spreadsheet response1= service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).setIncludeGridData (false).execute ();

List<Sheet> workSheetList = response1.getSheets();

for (Sheet sheet : workSheetList) {
    System.out.println(sheet.getProperties().getTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version

```
fun getSheets(): List<GSheetMeta> {
    return sheets.spreadsheets()
        .get("spreadsheetId")
        .setIncludeGridData(false)
        .execute()
        .sheets
        .map { GSheetMeta(it.properties.title, it.properties.sheetId) }
}
```

And model class

```
class GSheetMeta(val name: String, val id: Int) {

    override fun toString() = name
}
```