# Find a Google Drive Sheet By Name Using API 4 In Android

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I followed the "Android Quickstart" below.

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android

Works great.

But the sample hard-codes a spreadsheetId to an existing spreadsheet.

```
String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
```

**I need to be able to find an existing spreadsheet, *by name,* and store the id** (for later use).

I'd like to do something like this:

```
private com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets sheetsService = null;


HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

sheetsService = new com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets.Builder(
        transport, jsonFactory, credential)
        .setApplicationName("My Application Name")
        .build();

String spreadsheetId = null;
List<Spreadsheet> allSpreadsheets = sheetsService.spreadsheets().getAListOfAllSpreadsheets;
for (Spreadsheet spreadsheet : allSpreadsheets) {
    if (spreadsheet.getName().equals("My Sheet")){
        // found!
        spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    }
}
```

Much thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided in this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123383/how-to-get-sheet-name-of-individual-sheets-in-google-spreadsheet-google-sheet)? They used service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).setIncludeGridData (false)
.execute (); and then parsed the response using the getSheets() function.

Comment: @noogui I don't have a spreadsheetId to pass. I'd hate to create a sheet just to find a sheet. Thanks tho.

Comment: what you're doing is not even mentioned in the docs lol

Comment: Really API v4? 99.9% use 14+

Comment: @SebastianSchneider Just for clarity, when I say "v4" I'm referring to the google sheets api version (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/) not the android version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this cannot be done with Sheets API v4.

**However...it does look like it can be done with the compatible Google Drive API v3.**

Note: the best part about this solution was that I could use the same method of authentication and credential gathering for both APIs. E.g., once I had the code for getting the credentials, I could use it for both API's interchangeably and consecutively.

Here's what I did:

Added this to my `build.gradle` (shown below my Sheets API declaration)

```
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev468-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev69-1.22.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

I was already using the `EasyPermissions` method for getting account and credentials. [Great example here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android).

Then...

```
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
```

...

```
private static final String[] SCOPES = { SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS, DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY };
```

...

```
credentials = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
```

...

```
protected Drive driveService = new Drive.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("My Application Name")
            .build();

protected Sheets sheetsService = new Sheets.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("My Application Name")
            .build();
```

... async:

```
    Drive.Files.List request = driveService.files().list()
            .setPageSize(10)
            // Available Query parameters here:
            //https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters
            .setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and name contains 'smith' and trashed = false")
            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)");

    FileList result = request.execute();

    List<File> files = result.getFiles();
    String spreadsheetId = null;
    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {

            // More code here to discriminate best result, if you want
            spreadsheetId = file.getId();
        }
    }
```

Then you can directly use the id for the Sheets API:

```
    ValueRange response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, "A1:B2").execute();
    List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
```

Comment: I followed your code example, But I get 403, Insufficient Permission error message. I have implemented GoogleSheets API, which works before this code changes.

Comment: Ah, yes! I bet your lacking the the correct SCOPES. You probably need the `DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY` scope. I'll update the answer to include this. (I forgot that this was one of the steps I made when I was getting this to work.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're confusing `Spreadsheet` and `Sheet` objects:

- a `Spreadsheet` is a file with an Id, accessible by a URL such as https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/**yourSpreadsheetId**; it is a document stored in a Google Drive folder (like an Excel workbook).
- a `Sheet` is a tab in a `Spreadsheet`, with cells, like a page in your workbook. It has no Id and no direct URL. *Well actually the [API v4 reference](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SheetProperties) indicate that Sheets also have Ids, but confusingly enough these are just reference numbers that you cannot even access in Google Apps Script, and wouldn't help you in your problem*.

So you cannot access a range directly in a Spreadsheet, nor can you find a Sheet by Id.

Similarly enough to your answer, here is what I would suggest:

_ Browse through your Drive files (filter by `mimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"`)

__For each Spreadsheet file, browse its Sheets (`spreadsheet.sheets[]`)

___For each Sheet in the current Spreadsheet, check whether it's the one by looking at its name (`sheet.title`)

Once you found the right sheet, you can get its containing Spreadsheet's Id (`spreadsheet.spreadsheetId`).

One more thing: at the bottom of your answer, you wrote
`ValueRange response = sheetsService.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, "A1:B2").execute();`

You wouldn't be able to access a cell range from a spreadsheet without first specifying the Sheet containing the range: so instead of `"A1:B2"`, you would need `"mySheetTitle!A1:B2"`.

I hope this is clearing up the confusion :)

Comment: Updated question to be more clear about "sheet" vs. "spreadsheet." Great tip about the mimeType (updated answer to include that as a search criteria). Finally, You do NOT need the sheet qualifier in the range. The range setting is from tested code and works.

Comment: If the spreadsheet contains only one sheet then I trust you it works without specifying the sheet in the range; however if the spreadsheet contains multiple sheets (which is probably the most frequent case), then it wouldn't know which sheet to choose from.