# Is it possible to parse content URI to google drive document ID in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, google-api

I do not need to get the content of the file, I just need ID only! If this is impossible then the impossibility should be the answer.

I get the content URI from android intent [`ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) using flutter plugin [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker).

It work perfectly, but I need to get the selected [document ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061433/how-to-do-i-locate-a-google-spreadsheet-id) (spreadsheet ID, specifically) in Google Drive.

The URI I got looks like:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc%3D1%3Bdoc%3Dencoded%3DBEskNs6jf7jS24J%2FMnNdnr7fDrih03xNetfcCUsggemjSmpiWBC5
```

After using URL decoded it turns out to be like:

```
content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/acc=1;doc=encoded=BEskNs6jf7jS24J/MnNdnr7fDrih03xNetfcCUsggemjSmpiWBC5
```

The link provided by [Google Drive API v3: get FileID from Android content URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57435714/google-drive-api-v3-get-fileid-from-android-content-uri)

Is it possible to get the document ID from this URI? I have tried base64 decode, not working.

Or any suggestion to get the ID? Maybe create a custom UI showing documents and let user select?

My application helps edit spreadsheet by user selected. Here is some code to reproduce:

```dart
// The package will use Intent in android
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
// Should check null
final file = result!.files.first;
// Content URI
print(file.identity);
// File name
print(file.name);
```

Comment: Please include [example]

Comment: Done, using [package](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) make the code so easy that I'm not sure it is useful.

Comment: so what does print(file.id); do exactly?

Comment: Do you mean `identity`? It is the URI(`content://com.google...`) from [selected data](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/blob/443808b9cd350f8224169a2ebc5ceb555e2772d8/android/src/main/java/com/mr/flutter/plugin/filepicker/FilePickerDelegate.java#L96).

Comment: I found alternative solution: using [file's name to get ID by Driver API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345575/find-a-google-drive-sheet-by-name-using-api-4-in-android)